# iscroll not working in phonegap?how to use iscroll in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have created application in android phonegap.I have used iscoll for displaying scrollbar dynamically in div In that I have appended list and display dynamically.

It shows the div with appended list,but scroll bar is not displayed.

In logcat I got the following error:

`03-21 16:09:02.669: WARN/webview(2166): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down`.

My code is

I have used [cubiq.org/iscroll-4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for displaying scrollbar

js for scrollbar is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="iscroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

function for displaying scrollbar

```
var scroll1;
function loaded() {
    scroll1 = new iScroll('standard');


}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
</script>
```

css for scrollbar

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">

body {
    font-size:12px;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    font-family:helvetica;
    padding:20px;
}

#standard {
    position:relative; z-index:1;
    display:block; float:left;
    width:100px; height:150px;
    background:#aaa;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}

#standard {
    margin-right:20px;
}

.scroller {
    position:absolute; z-index:1;

    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
```

I have appended list with `div(id="list")` and appended button with `div(id="button")`

```
<div id="standard">
    <div class="scroller">
         <div id="button"></div>
       <div id="list">

       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

how to display scroollbar with dynamic div.?please guide me. thanks in advance

Comment: thats no error Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about horizontal scroll, when property **hScroll** is defaulted as true. If it's vertical, you need to set **vScroll** as true also, when creating the iScroll element.

If you're having a dynamically generated list, you need to use `scroll1.refresh()` to notice generated content.

Also, having `overflow:auto` for #standard is unnecessary since iScroll switches it to `overflow:hidden`.

But like stated in the documentation, best way to get iScroll to work, is to have structure as (which I assume you already have):

```
<div id='ScrollWrapper'>
<ul>
  <li>content</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hai ,thanks for your reply.where I set to vScroll=true and where I use scroll1.refresh() please guide me.thanks in advance.

Comment: My mistake: hScroll is defaulted as false, while vScroll is true. But you can toggle these in parameters, eg: scroll1 = new iScroll('standard' {'vScroll':true});

And use .refresh() whenever you add dynamic content to the scroller area.